# 1st SQL request slower than other with cold cache

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I can't find why my 1st request is slower. I clean the cache in every loop but i still have a large difference.

```
    DECLARE @t1 DATETIME;
DECLARE @t2 DATETIME;
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;
DECLARE @myTable TABLE  
    ( passage INT NOT NULL, 
    timer   INT   NOT NULL);  



WHILE @cnt < 10
BEGIN 
    DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS 

    SET @t1 = GETDATE();
        SELECT [IdElement]
  , [IdElementary]
  FROM [dbo].[Elementest]
  WHERE IdelementAccount = 1
    SET @t2 = GETDATE();

    INSERT INTO @myTable (timer, passage) VALUES (DATEDIFF(millisecond,@t1,@t2), @cnt);
    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;

END;

SELECT * FROM @myTable
```

And the timer's results in ms are:

970

63

66

63

70

70

66

60

60

66

Comment: You're not clearing the plan cache (just the data cache), so the difference could very well be the plan compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RDBMS caches query results into memory for faster access. Even, frequently accessed queries are cached as well so that execution served from memory instead of disk.

Depending on the structure of your SQL Queries, the execution times may vary. Also, reserved memory for SQL has very big role on caching. If the reserved memory is low then your RDBMS releases its cache frequently for opening space for new coming DML operations.

So, in this case, it is better to concentrate on resource usage and optimizer specific tunings.

I believe that you may get more help from [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks, is there any solution for cleaning that?

Comment: why do you want to clean? it is implicit feature, why do you care?

Comment: I try to replicate my production working as much as possible. 
In my product this query will be execute with different where clauses multiple time in a day and cost a lot of time. If i understand this will cost 900 ms each time?

Comment: are your queries parameterized or dynamic? depending on their structure the execution times may vary. Also, reserved memory for SQL has very big role on caching. If the reserved memory is low then your RDBMS releases its cache for opening space for new coming DML operations.

Comment: They are dynamic. the SELECT remains the same but the WHERE clauses are dynamics.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the difference is the query plan.  You have a parameterized query, so the first run compiles the query and stores the plan in a query cache.  I'm surprised that would take 900 milliseconds but it seems a likely cause for the delay.